# What does the insert key do in macOS?

Tags: terminal, keyboard

This key is basically useless unless you need overtype mode. In Windows Command Prompt, pressing it toggles overtype. But, in  macOS Terminal, it doesn't even work. How do I get the insert key to toggle overtype in Terminal, and does it have any other use cases in macOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It serves no purpose whatsoever and is not even present on Apple keyboards. macOS does not have an 'insert' mode.

It registers as Keycode 114 & is titled 'Help', but it has no default function on macOS.

```
Characters: 
Unicode:    63302 / 0xf746
Keys:       Help
Key Code:   114 / 0x72
Modifiers:  8388864 / 0x800100
```

According to [Overtype mode in Terminal.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138942/overtype-mode-in-terminal-app) you can switch to Vim keybindings, which will then enable an insert mode, though I've never tried this.